# rewrite dynamic file link and change ending from php into js

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi im using a php script where im grab js files, minify and compress them and set a last modified header.
On my html i added my main js file as php file (the number is changing constantly):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_scripts.071.php" ></script>
```

So i found a rule to remove the dynamic part `jquery_scripts.071.php` -> `jquery_scripts.php` as follow:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.\d+(\.(?:php))$ $1$2
```

How can i change this rewriteRule to rewrite `jquery_scripts.071.js` -> `jquery_scripts.php`

EDIT:
I tried something like that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.\d+(\.(?:js))$ $1.php
```

But isnt working.

Comment: Your questions is unclear. If you already managed to write the posted rule, then why do you have issues modifying it? And if you only copied the rule, wouldn't it make sense to understand it prior to using it?

Comment: @arkascha yeah im mod_rewrite learning at the moment but its still not clear for me how this work exactly (and yes its copied). I edited the question a bit so its more clear. But at all its just to add the js to php part.

Comment: Start by not trying to match as much as possible dynamically (which probably doesn't make the most sense here anyway), but keep the parts of the file name that are constant, "static" in your rule pattern as well. Go figure out a regular expression that would match `jquery_scripts.`, then some/three digits, and then `.js`

Comment: @CBroe something like `RewriteRule ^(jquery_scripts\.)$ ^$1.php`

Comment: `$` means "has to end here", so that would match `jquery_scripts.` only. Try something like `^(jquery_scripts\.[0-9]{3})\.js$` - `jquery_scripts.` followed by three (quantifier `{9}`) digits (character class `[0-9]`), and the final `.js` matched outside the capturing round braces.

Comment: The match is working already, but the second part is not working (the link jquery_script.php).

Comment: @delato468 second part is working fine

Comment: @Mohammed Elhag `^$1.php` should be really correct for second part ? @CBroe thanks i will try later. If i dont need the digits for second part, i leave them outside capturing round braces? Does the "." inside round braces get escaped for storing too ?

Comment: if im using this RewriteRule `(^jquery_scripts\.)[0-9]{3}\.js$ https://example.com` i still get internel server error for `https://example.com/jquery_scripts.071.js`

Comment: @CBroe  oh dear i think i found the problem why i could not be successful with anything. Because im handling js files with nginx and for nginx i need to do that somehow different... Can you help me there too ?

Comment: because of that: `location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|woff|svg)$ {
 expires 7d; ...}` so nginx would aff a expire header but cant find the file. Its working if i remove js and css above but i have some files too wich im adding on the fly, so i cant disable there :(.

Comment: Too complete my last answers, im using now complete nginx and used your patterns. Everything is working fine now thanks.